# Question regarding what appears to be an identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

This is an MCQ  we were posed in school recently (I hope you don't mind elementary stuff):

What is $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)...(x-z)$ ?
Options:

$0$

$1$

$2$

$(x^n)-(abcdef...z)$

Comment: Are you sure it didn't go up to $x-z$?

Comment: @mixedmath Surely it did, or else none of the choices is correct (not that I particularly like the "solution" in that case).

Comment: Oh yes, it did. I'm so sorry. But the last option was still $x^n - (abc...z)$ AFAIK. I lost the test paper :(

Comment: How does it matter if it's $n$ or $z$?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury The fact that $n$ or $z$ actually makes a difference is something you should think about.

Comment: I've always liked this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very basic trick to this problem.  It all comes down to a single term (if that's the proper word for it...).

The only real hint I can give is $x$ is a letter between $a$ and $z$...

Comment: +1, Very cool! Also,  Thank you @DonAntonio for pointing where I went wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see... $(x-a)(x-b)..(x-x)..(x-z)$ where $(x-x)$ is 0. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ What is $\rm\ (24-1)(24-2)(24-3)\cdots (24-26)\ $ ?

And what is $\rm\,(x_{24}\!-x_1)(x_{24}\!-x_2)(x_{24}\!-x_3)\cdots (x_{24}\!-x_{26})\ $ ?

Comment: @Thanks for the hint. Very good point.